# Testing post on Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading to Rails 5.1.2 the following test fails immediately

```
post :methodName

unexpected invocation: #<BufferedLogger:0x7fd141203248>.info('Processing by Controller#methodName as HTML')
```

My routes look like

```
namespace :controllername do
    post :methodName
end
```

Is there something I'm missing to make this work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `Rails.logger.expects` in my test which caused this issues.